# Avoiding Conversions (or an EAV model)

Tags: database-design, r

I was given the task to turn some really messy data into a database. Coming from an Stats/R/Data Science background, I took Hadley Wickham's philosophy of tidy data as a starting point.

However, when gaining more and more understanding of the data, I was confronted with quite a peculiar problem.

The data consists of repeated measures performed on several units of observation. Each time, many parameters are measured in different units. Some values are strings, some numeric. Additionally, I have quite a bit of meta information about the parameters.

A first concise data structure I wrangled the stuff into looks something like this:

| parameter | meta_info | unit | obs_id | time | value | product | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| param_1 | info_para_1 | v | 1 | 1 | string_value | A | string |
| param_2 | info_para_2 | mg/ml | 1 | 1 | numeric_value | A | numeric |
| param_1 | info_para_1 | v | 2 | 1 | string_value | A | string |

Note that meta_infos are only constant within product.

After doing some research, I found out that this should correspond to an EAV model if I am not mistaken.

The obvious downside of storing the values as strings is that I would have to reshape the data every time I pull it into R and convert the values to their proper data types in order to plot stuff for instance. Same holds if I want to automatically generate CSVs in order for the non-tech savy folks to be able to play around with the data.

Are there any alternative or better models to store the data?

For instance, one that takes the "conversion/reshaping/merging" action to the level of the meta_infos as I will probably use them to a lesser extent.

Comment: EAV is more of an anti-pattern - can store lot of things but querying them can become a nightmare quickly. Do you need to "work" with that data inside the DB (aggregating them or filtering by them etc) or do you just need to pull all data for given `(observation, time)` (or similar identifier) as a "batch" and only process it in R?

Comment: Well I will use the DB only to store and will pull batches into R, mostly for plotting/summarizing purposes. Reshaping from the EAV model to something I can work with would be like 3 lines of code.

Comment: As the meta data is not that important for the daily workflow, I think I will just put it into an extra table and reshape the above (parameter names as variables). The two tables will be semi-relational (via product) and I would have to reshape the main table to an EAV-type table to merge it with the meta info. But as I expect that to be a rare task that's the easiest solution I can come up with. Curious if there are cool models for this rather common problem I am totally unaware of.

Comment: If you only need to store and retrieve the data that way, I would only care about structures for the metadata. The data can be stored some serialized way - one common way is JSON - you just define a text (or json if supported by your db) column and put the data there. JSON support in the DB might allow you to work with the data using SQL if sometime needed too. Another way would be to store it in a blob and use R (de)serialize functions. That way the data itself is entirely opaque to the DB and you just don't care about it.

Comment: That's a very reasonable suggestion and I will run with something along the lines. You can convert our comment into an answer. If not, the question can be considered as closed. Data-base design is context dependent but spelling it out and your comments helped me to think through it.